# Merging two mp3s with Mp3Wrap

Tags: audio, command-line

I want to merge two files so that they play at the same time. can I do this with mp3wrap, or is there another program?

It needs to be from the command line.

I want something like

```
> Mp3Wrap output.mp3 s1.mp3 -s s2.mp3 -s s3.mp3 -s s4.mp3 s5.mp3
```

the `-s` means that the file will overlap the one before it, instead of adding it afterwards. Are there any command line programs do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java, C#, VB.NET, and many others programming languages can run command line statements.

Comment: How does this help me? using C++ with the command line doesn't give Mp3Wrap any more functions O.O
Im trying to use Sox now anyways.

Comment: If it does not support out of the box and you want to modify MP3 wrap. Mp3Wrap is Open Source (under GPL License), you could add more functionality into it. O.O

Comment: SoX seems to work good anyways, only one problem, but its a bug, so theres no point in asking. **Thankyou for the answers :P**